# Получить XML-данные из URLAjax: get xml data from url

Tags: javascript, ajax

Функция `status` возвращает `0` для моего AJAX-запроса. Однако при его исполнении через инструменты разработчика возвращается код `200`.

Чем вызвано это различие и как его устранить?

```
function Privat24Info(){
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("GET", " https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?exchange&coursid=5", true);
            request.send();
            alert(request.status);
        }
```

Comment: асинхронность: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_xmlhttprequest_first

Comment: @Igor спасибо разобрался нужно было 2 аргументом использовать false в параметрах request.open();

Comment: нет, не нужно. Нужно в правильном месте проверять `request.status`, как показано в примере по ссылке.